# Trying to understand table relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.3

I just started studying Laravel and as my starter I am following this tutorial video series.
https://youtu.be/Y1TkLkGhHwA

I am trying to understand how these two table relation works at Model level.

Order.php

```
public function customer(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
}
```

I kind of understand this is how Laravel makes relationship between two tables by using `belongsTo` method. (I just accept it as it is)

But when I use this model in other model, `customer()` function defined in `Order.php` becomes a property(?) of object instance($order->**customer**->name). This is the part I don't get or just lack of OOP knowledge...

Routes\web.php

```
Route::get('orders',function(){
    $orders = App\Order::all();
    foreach($orders as $order){
        echo $order->name . 'belongs to' . $order->customer->name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your worry, you are just confused with what is called **Eager Loading**. You can learn more about that here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

What happens is, behind the scenes Laravel lazy loads the 'customer' data for you in a single query. So in your foreach example, if you have 10 orders, 10 different queries will be executed to get the customer data.

Next time you do, let's say, `$order->customer->email`, it wont make another query because that customer data was already loaded during the first query.

Follow the link I gave you above, you will discover amazing stuff.

Comment: I read the documentation as you recommended and I kinda get it. Thanks for the info. To quote `When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property`.  I additionally got the idea of "Eager load" and "Lasy Load" that Laravel offers. Thanks again for that!

Comment: My pleasure, if my answer helped with your query, please mark it as solved. Thanks :)

Comment: I notice that when using Eager Load, function name has to be same as model name. This works: `public function customer()` but this doesn't `public function foo()`. I thought this could be any name.

Comment: Just tested your theory. I change some of my relationships name, they still work. Usually I just follow convention.

Comment: Please take a look at my code example. I am working on Laravel 5.3 http://ideone.com/JObIQJ

Comment: Can you try not to use foo? Maybe let's try with 'user()'. Because I have some videos and renamed the relationship to 'links'. It still works fine. Besides, relationship are simly function that return an Instance of the model. Now, try with using with. Simply do `$orders = Order::get()`; Then try to call it. Sorry I cannot comment on the link you gave me.

Comment: If I put 2nd argument which I believe foreign key, it worked fine. `return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer', 'customer_id');`Then the function name can now go with any name `foo()` or `bar()` or whatever.